# sh -c "echo $SOMEVAR" messing up

Tags: bash

I am writing a complex bash script invoked using `sh -c 'bash in here'`. But when I attempt to set a variable I get very strage behavior:

`sh -c "SOMEVAR=$(expr 1 - 2) && echo $SOMEVAR"` outputs `1` when it should be `-1`!

As far as I understand, `$(expr 1 - 2)` evaluates to `-1`.  So essentially this script is `SOMEVAR=-1 && echo SOMEVAR` returning `1`.

What do I not understand about Bash?  What is wrong with my script?

Comment: I get `-1` when I run that.

Comment: @icktoofay : I posted single quotes when the fail was because I was using double quotes.  I figured it out and answered my own question.  Thanks for being helpful :)

Comment: nitpick: it should be either `sh -c 'sh code in here'` or `bash -c 'bash code in here'`. but not `sh -c 'bash code in here'`. bash can do some stuff which sh cannot.

Comment: @lesmana : thanks, that's good to know.  That might fix another problem I was having...

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what Bash was doing: because I was using double quotes (`"`), my variable's (`SOMEVAR`) outside value (which was `1`) was being inserted into the `sh -c` stuff making the run code actually:

```
sh -c "SOMEVAR=$(expr 1 - 2) && echo 1"
```

instead of:

```
sh -c "SOMEVAR=$(expr 1 - 2) && echo $SOMEVAR"
```

Solution: use single quotes (`'`)

```
sh -c 'SOMEVAR=$(expr 1 - 2) && echo $SOMEVAR'
```